# Getting a DC value from this driver circuit

Tags: dc, filter, driver

I have this driver circuit that I can't change:

[image: Circuit]

V1 is always 24 V. V2 can be 3.3 V or 0 V.

The output of this driver goes to the board that I'm developing.

If V2 is a PWM, would it be possible to get a DC voltage from this circuit by using some filtering components?

I tried adding a resistor and a capacitor in a low-pass filter configuration, but it doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123370/discussion-on-question-by-marcos-getting-a-dc-value-from-this-driver-circuit).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a warm welcome to the forum and some nice advices, a user suggested to add a pull up resistor to my original circuit. This is, indeed, a good answer to my question (R1 in the picture below):

[image: Circuit]

Then, a simple RC filter (R2 and C1) will attenuate the high frequencies from the PWM (V1).

Values V2, R1, R2, PWM duty cycle (d), and load to this circuit will determine the output voltage in steady state. In my case, the output impedance is very high, so considering it infinitely large, one gets:

$$\overline{v_{C1}}=\frac{R2 V2}{d R1+R2}(1-d)$$

The time constant for a constant duty cycle can be calculated as well. This gives and idea of the dynamic response of this circuit:

$$\tau=\frac{C1 R2(R1+R2)}{d R1+R2}$$

If the load is a resistor of value R3 (i.e. it's not infinite anymore), the maximum output voltage is really easy to get:

$$v_{C1max}=\frac{R3 V2}{R1+R2+R3}$$

But the time constant will also change, and will be slower by a factor of:

$$1+\frac{R2(R1+R2)}{(d R1+R2)R3}$$